# PHP Upload images script

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
function secure_img_upload($file, $path, $options = array()){
 // HANDLE OPTIONS
 $validExtensions = isset($options['validExtensions']) ? $options['validExtensions'] : array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
 $surfix = isset($options['surfix']) ? $options['surfix'] : '';

 // HANDLES FILES
 $tempFile           =    $file['tmp_name'];
 $fileName         =    $file['name'];
 $extension    =   explode(".", $fileName);
 $extension    =    strtolower(end($extension));
 $imageName        =    sha1($fileName.uniqid());
 $destination  =   rtrim($path, '/').'/'.$imageName.$surfix.'.'.$extension;

 if(in_array($extension, $validExtensions)) {
     $validExtension        =    true;    
 } else {
     $validExtension        =    false;    
 }

 // Run getImageSize function to check that we're really getting an image
 if(getimagesize($tempFile) == false) {
     $validImage        =    false;    
 } else {
     $validImage        =    true;    
 }

 if($validExtension == true && $validImage == true) {
     if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $destination)) {
      return $destination;
     }else{
      return array('s'=>'ko', 'm'=>T("Invalid path."));
     }
    }else{
     return array('s'=>'ko', 'm'=>T("Invalid extension."));
    }
}
```

My problem is that in this way, Images are uploaded in a random way.
But I need that images are uploaded in the order I select them. Any tips? Thank you

Comment: how are you doing the files? a single input[type=file] with multi, or a bunch of different file inputs?

Comment: a single input with multi

Comment: then you're dependent on browser behavior for which order things are sent in.

Comment: perhaps research a javascript plug in on the `form` to order the images in the way they're given so the browser can't (easily) reorder them as they're submitted ?

Comment: Also Gixone, what you're showing in your question is the function that does the work, but if you can EDIT your question - can you also show how this function is applied to the `$_FILES` data on the page? This can help to see if there's a possibility of ordering the `$_FILES` array of files to preserve any ordering of upload.